# RatingBar does not show 'numStars' stars

Tags: android, recyclerview-layout

The activity has a RecyclerView which consists of multiple card_layouts
A card_layout has a full ImageView and RatingBar.

I set the 'numStars' of RatingBar to show the maximum rating score
and use 'setRating' to set the actual rate within Java code.

However, the RatingBar does not have 'numStars' stars.

What did I do wrong?

Here is xml code of my RatingBar

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|left"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        android:numStars="5"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        android:transformPivotX="8dp"
        android:transformPivotY="8dp" />
```

I appreciate your help

Comment: can i ask what you are meaning by the ratingbar does not have "numStars" stars ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can try numStars progrmatically using this syntax:

ratingbar.setNumStars(int numStars);

You can refer to this doc for other additional info on rating bar;

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar

If still the rating (stars) still not showing or rendering , you can try these steps:

- check the ratingbar container
- check your model holding the value for ratings

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! I used the 'setNumStars' API, but it does not work!
Cold you more elaborate on the next two steps? (checking the container? and model?)